# Annotation as shortcut for another annotation

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, spring-annotations, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using both Spring data Mongodb and Elasticsearch and syncing them at real-time.

I'm using the same Spring entities for both cases, something that looks like this:

```
// imports and stuff
@Document(collection="something")
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "something")
public class MySomething {
// class definition...
```

This works fine... My issue is that I would like to replace the fully qualified name for the elasticsearch annotation with a "shortcut" annotation, something like `@ElasticDocument`.

One solution would be to copy `@Doucment` entirely into a new annotation then override it's multiple usages with the new annotation => This will create a load of unnecessary code (considering that I'll have to override multiple Spring data elasticsearch config classes) for only an esthetic reason!

Is there another more elegant solution ? One which involves "renaming" `@Document` or creating a shortcut annotation for it ?

I can't seem to think of a suitable solution considering `@interface` polymorphism is not possible in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is the correct answer, but have you considered taking a look at Spring's `@AliasFor` annotation? It could be what you are looking for. For example, you could try something like this and see how it goes:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
public @interface ElasticDocument {

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "indexName")
    String indexName() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "type")
    String type() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "useServerConfiguration")
    boolean useServerConfiguration() default false;

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "shards")
    short shards() default 5;

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "replicas")
    short replicas() default 1;

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "refreshInterval")
    String refreshInterval() default "1s";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "indexStoreType")
    String indexStoreType() default "fs";

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "createIndex")
    boolean createIndex() default true;

    @AliasFor(annotation = Document.class, attribute = "versionType")
    VersionType versionType() default VersionType.EXTERNAL;

}
```

Note, I haven't tested the above code but you could give it a go and see how it goes.